# Record Touch Event in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, record

I want to record touch events in iOS. I've read in some forums that IOHIDFamily can be used for this. But i couldnt find much information this. How can i use IOHIDFamily or some other method to record touch events in iOS

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Within Xcode, you can try UIAutomation instrument. For third-party tool, Monkey Talk might be a good choice.